# Access Directories & Files

Tags: c, file-io, directory

I was wondering, I am writing a program in C, and I writing the output from my program to a csv file.  This works locally, and I can create and update the file with no errors.

But on the server, where I need to store the file - I do not have permissions to write to that file/directory.  Is there a work around for getting around the permissions problems?

Comment: what way do you use to store the file on server ? probably the best way is to write/update locally and then store on server again

Comment: All the processing is completed live on the server - there's no way to create a local version unfortunately.

Comment: have the server send the ouput to another machine, is that a possible option ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can run your program as a more authorative user, such as root.

There is no simple way from the program itself to just ignore the operating system's security model, that would make it quite pointless.

Note that if you're not the administrator on the server, you're likely not even allowed to run programs as root.

Finally, writing C programs that manipulate files and directories and then running them as root on a server is a fine way of shooting yourself in the foot. Be careful.

Comment: You're quite right, it does ignore the operating system and why I have the user rights that I do have on the server.  I had not thought of it like that.

I'll see if I can run it as the root user and see if I can do that.